# I want to change clock from 12h to 24h mode via terminal

Tags: terminal, settings

So I'm looking for the command to change from 12h to 24h. Is there even such a command? I mean I can do it with the GUI but I need to be able to do it via terminal so I can put it in a bash script.

[image]

Here I want instead of the 12h format a 24h format.

Comment: Do you mean to convert a given time? Or alter your system time display preference? Or something else?

Comment: I want to alter my system time display preference (so the time display at the top right). I'll add this to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is stored in the plist located at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.menuextra.clock` under the key `DateFormat`.

Here's a quick primer:

- 12 Hour Mode with AM/PM:

  `EEE MMM d  h:mm:ss a`
- 12 Hour Mode without AM/PM:

  `EEE MMM d  h:mm:ss`
- 24 Hour Mode:

  `EEE MMM d  H:mm:ss`

To apply any of these formatting strings, you can either use the `defaults` command at the Terminal, or if you're looking for a more programmable method, you can use the `do shell script`<sup>1</sup> directive within Applescript.

To apply these via the Terminal, open it up and run the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock DateFormat -string 'EEE MMM d  H:mm:ss'
```

Substitute the string between the quotes with the version from above that you want.

For the changes to take immediate effect, `kill -SIGHUP SystemUIServer` will do the trick. Otherwise they will take effect the next time you log out and back in or restart.

---

<sup>1</sup> [CyberCiti Primer on Shell Scripting via Applescript](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mac-osx-applescript-run-shell-script/)

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Yosemite 10.10.3. After I log off and log on again, the DateFormat is reset.

Comment: So it *does* work for you, it just doesn't persist.

Comment: The changes can be made immediately by restarting `SystemUIServer`. I've edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that my date was stuck in 12h format no matter what setting I chose in System Settings. The answer above pointed me in the right direction. It looks like on macOS Ventura this has changed a bit. I was able to set it to 24h format with this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock Show24Hour 1
```

First I could read all the data with this:

```
defaults read com.apple.menuextra.clock
```