# Removing the automatic connection for 802.1X via terminal

Tags: terminal, network

So in the spirit of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/i-want-to-change-clock-from-12h-to-24h-mode-via-terminal) I was wondering if it is possible to disable automatic 802.1X connection via terminal as well.
Am I right to assume that this is a computer setting (meaning that if I run this script with no user logged in it still disables it for all existing and future users)?

Answer (score 2):

It took me some hours to learn that it's a boolean value (and not just 0 or 1 as 'defaults' would report) but finally i came up with the following [LoginHook](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420) which does the trick. As LoginHooks get
executed as root user, you have to 'su' to the user currently being logged
in before running the script below. As Michele points out below, that username
is available as $1 to the Hook-Script running as root.
It seems to be a user byHost-Setting, although SystemPrefs would ask for a admin password to tweak this setting...
My hook script being executed in user-context looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ `whoami` = "root" ]; then
  echo "$0: Must run as regular user, not root! QUIT."
  exit 1
fi

# write new setting 
defaults write -currentHost com.apple.network.eapolcontrol EthernetAutoConnect -bool false
```

Using opensnoop(1) or fs_usage(1) I could not see any other files being modified. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is what we implemented at work.  It runs as a login script for each user that logs into the computer.  Since OS X 10.9, the location has changed and the file name is different for each user.  The script looks for the unique file for that user and changes the auto connect value.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

### Variables
user=`/usr/bin/logname`
x=$(find ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost -name "com.apple.network.eapolcontrol*.plist")

### Functions

defaults write $x EthernetAutoConnect -bool false
```

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the *Enable automatic* connection tickbox in the 802.1x tab of your advanced interface option as it is the equivalent of the terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this solution can work, since a [LoginHook](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420) is executed as `root` and not as the user itself.

Here my solution:

```
#! /bin/sh
su - $1 -c "defaults -currentHost write com.apple.network.eapolcontrol EthernetAutoConnect -bool false";
```

Note that the option `-currentHost` will do the stuff with the host uuid ;-)

Cheers,
Michele

Comment: Does this work, the first clause confuses me, also what do you pass in as a parameter to the script?

Comment: The parameter `$1` ist the username, which is automatically passed to this script by the LoginHook.